# iOS undefined symbol errors linking with libOmnitureAppMeasurement-iPhoneSimulator.a

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, adobe-analytics, undefined-symbol, i386

I'm building app usage tracking into an iOS iPad app (iOS 6.1 and newer) using the Omniture App Measurement libraries.

As there are seperate libraries for device and simulator, I'm using the one for the simulator: libOmnitureAppMeasurement-iPhoneSimulator.a

- I've downloaded and unzipped the library and header into folder
  iPhoneAppMeasurement in my project (this folder contains the files
  libOmnitureAppMeasurement-iPhoneSimulator.a and OMAppMeasurement.h
  which have been correctly added to the project)
- I ensured that the library is pointed to correctly in my library
  search path under build settings.
- I added the Omniture SDK setup and a few test calls in the code.

When I build I get Undefined symbol errors of the type "Pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name" ...

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  ".objc_class_name_NSArray", referenced from:
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libOmnitureAppMeasurement-iPhoneSimulator.a(OMAppMeasurement.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSBundle", referenced from:
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libOmnitureAppMeasurement-iPhoneSimulator.a(OMAppMeasurement.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSDate", referenced from:
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libOmnitureAppMeasurement-iPhoneSimulator.a(OMAppMeasurement.o)

... etc ...

  ".objc_class_name_UIScreen", referenced from:
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libOmnitureAppMeasurement-iPhoneSimulator.a(OMAppMeasurement.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OMAppMeasurement", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in OmnitureEvent.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I get these both for the iPad 6.1 and iPad 7.0 simulators. How can I resolve this?

UPDATES:
From feedback and other articles I took the following steps...

```
- I added libstdc++ under Apple LLVM 5.0 -Language C++ settings
- I changed Other Linker flags under Build Settings->Linking to use -libstdc++ 
  (instead of lstdc++)
- I ensured libstdc++.dylib was included under Build Phases 

Now I get "Apple Mach-O Linker Error" ld: library not found for -libstdc++
```

Is there a way I can do a command line find to check for the existence of libstdc++.dylib  and then set/include it in my project? That may not be an ideal approach but I need to get this fixed!

Comment: Xcode seems to be complaining about Foundation classes... Might be an obvious question, but is the Foundation framework properly linked against your project?

Comment: Actually I forgot to add the rest of the lines. Yes the code built and ran just fine before I added the Omniture calls and libraries ... at the top (bottom) of the error stack is the Omniture class (added that to trace above)

Comment: Did you try adding the path to `libOmnitureAppMeasurement-iPhoneSimulator.a` to the "Other Linker Flags" settings of your project? (also known as `OTHER_LDFLAGS`). I understand that you did the necessary step for the Headers Search Path, but you might be missing this one?

Comment: Another thing: for what iOS SDK is your library built? It might also be the next thing to look at: different base SDKs between the library and your project...

Comment: Built for iOS 6 and iOS 7. Thanks for the suggestion on other linker flags: I get the above errors when the other linker flags are set to -lstdc++. When I set other linker flags to -libstdc++ I get just one error "library not found for libstdc++"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the Adobe Analytics API has been overhauled and the new API is AdobeMobileLibrary-4.0.2-iOS.zip

Under:
https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/gallery/app-measurement-for-ios

The usage is a different flavor and following the documentation it builds and runs just fine.
It appears libOmnitureAppMeasurement.... has been deprecated.